# How to decide on number of neurons in RNN?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to RNN and trying to understand them. Since it takes a sequence of input then the number of neurons should be the same as the size of the sequence, right? So, if we have 10 time-steps and thus 10 different inputs then, we should have 10 neurons, correct?

Also, does the number of neurons increase as time increases? So how can we fix the number of neurons?

In Keras, the GRU layer takes the number of units, what is this number? Is it the number of neurons? In the documentation, they say it is the size of the output. Then, where do we specify the number of neurons?

Comment: No, the number of neurons does not have to be the same as the size of the sequence (whatever that means).

Comment: No, that is not how RNNs work, the number of neurons is independent of the size of the sequence. You are somehow assuming that each neuron is input a timestep at a time (and only once), and that is not how it works.